# naturalHeight comparison with naturalWidth

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare the height and width of a series of images kept in a list.
However upon running this, the 'if' statement runs the "else" console.log in every instance.

no other errors are shown. According to chrome debugger, all the images have a 'naturalHeight' and 'naturalWidth' numerical value set.

Can anyone help me out?

```js
setImgSize(myList);

function setImgSize(list){

 var elementChildren = list.children;
 for (var i = 0; i < elementChildren.length; i++) {
     

     if (list.children[i].children[0].natualHeight > list.children[i].children[0].natualWidth){
      console.log("is Heigher");
     }
     else if (list.children[i].children[0].natualHeight <= list.children[i].children[0].natualWidth){
      console.log("is Longer");
     }
     else {
      console.log("bypassed");
     };

 };
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_5664ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_5945ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_5334ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_6067ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_4280ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_6367ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_5141ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_2823ed.jpg"></img></li>
      <li class="lfwImg"><img src="images/LFW/_MG_4501ed.jpg"></img></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`natualHeight`

Look veeeeeeery closely at that word... =)

It's probably just finding that `NaN` is neither less than nor greater than nor equal to `NaN`. (You have the same typo on naturalWidth too)

Comment: Thanks Katana, can't trust my own eyes ;)